# Getting 4-band raster from gdal_calc.py

Tags: gdal

I have 4 channel rasters in GeoTIFF.

[image A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA0vs.png)
[image B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW8YZ.png)

I need to find the average value of these rasters and present them in the form of another raster, also in RGB, and I get a black and white file.

[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgFVf.png)

How can I get rid of this?

```
gdal_calc.py -A /var/www/html/algorithm/cut103.tif -B /var/www/html/algorithm/cut1031.tif  -- 
outfile=result.tif --calc="(A+B)/2"
```

I also tried to use `gdal_translate -of VRT input.tif input.vrt`

My input.vrt:

```
<ColorInterp>Palette</ColorInterp>
<ColorTable>
<Entry c1="170" c2="170" c3="255"/>
<Entry c1="85" c2="170" c3="255"/>
<Entry c1="66" c2="33" c3="18"/>
<Entry c1="159" c2="81" c3="42"/>
<Entry c1="205" c2="169" c3="21"/>
<Entry c1="253" c2="254" c3="3"/>
<Entry c1="230" c2="236" c3="6"/>
<Entry c1="208" c2="223" c3="0"/>
<Entry c1="185" c2="207" c3="2"/>
<Entry c1="162" c2="192" c3="0"/>
<Entry c1="138" c2="175" c3="0"/>
<Entry c1="114" c2="160" c3="0"/>
<Entry c1="91" c2="142" c3="3"/>
<Entry c1="69" c2="129" c3="0"/>
<Entry c1="45" c2="112" c3="0"/>
<Entry c1="37" c2="96" c3="45"/>
<Entry c1="21" c2="84" c3="45"/>
<Entry c1="21" c2="68" c3="45"/>
```

Please someone, help

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the community https://gis.stackexchange.com/
the answer was found.
To solve the problem, you must first calculate each channel using gdal_calk --A_band, and then, using gdal_merge, merge the channels into an RGB raster.